# Find by many conditions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is a search action in RoR that can handle some params e.g.:

```
params[:name] # can be nil or first_name
params[:age]        # can be nil or age 
params[:city]    # can be nil or country
params[:tag]    # can be nil or country
```

The model name is `Person`. It also `has_many :tags`.

When finding persons I need like to AND all the conditions that are present. Of course, it not rational and not DRY.

What I tried to do:

```
conditions = []
conditions << [ "name like ?", params[:name]+"%" ] if params[:name].present?
conditions << [ "age = ?", params[:age] ] if params[:age].present?
conditions << [ "city = like ?", params[:city]+"%" ] if params[:city].present?
@persons = Person.all(:conditions => conditions )
#What about tags?  How do include them if params[:tag].present?
```

Of course, I want my code to be DRY. Now it's not. Even more, it will cause an exception if `params[:age]` and `params[:name]` and `params[:city]` are not present.

How can I solve? And how do I include tags for persons filtered by `tag.name=params[:tag]` (if `params[:tag].present?`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

lets say filters parameters include this:

```
filters = {
  :name_like => "Grienders",
  :age_equal => 15
}
```

Now you define methods for each

```
class Person
  def search_with_filters(filters)
    query = self.scoped
      filters.each do |key, values|
        query = query.send(key, values)
      end
    return query
  end

  def name_like(name)
    where("name like ?", name)
  end

  def age_equal(age)
    where(:age => age
  end
end
```

Do you see the method search_with_filters will be the "controlling" method that will take a set of query conditions (name_like, age_equal, etc...) and pass them out to matching method name using the send method, and along with that we also pass the condition which will be the parameter of the method.
The reason why this way is good is because you can scale to any number of conditions (your filter lets say get huge) and also the code is very clean because all you have to do is populate your filters parameter.  The method is very readable and very modular and also easy to test

Answer (score 0):

To include the tags condition in your query:

```
if params[:tag].present?
  @persons = Person.all(:conditions => conditions).includes(:tags).where("tags.name = ?", params[:tag])
else
  @persons = Person.all(:conditions => conditions)
end
```

As for there error you are getting when params[:age] .. is not present - This is very strange because it is supposed to return false incase the key is not set in params. Could you please paste the error you are getting?

Comment: params[:tag] can be not present. It has to be checked first.

Comment: Edited my answer with the params[:tag] check

Comment: I have no error now. However as far as I'm concerned you code doesn't seem DRY. Is there any way to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

I would work extensively with scopes for this. Starting with default scope, merge other scopes based on conditions.

Write scopes (or class methods):

```
class Person << AR::Base
  ...
  NAME_PARTS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
  scope :by_name, lambda { |q| where([NAME_PARTS.join(' LIKE :q OR ') + ' LIKE :q', { :q => "%#{q}%" }]) }
  scope :by_email, lambda { |q| joins(:account).where(["accounts.email LIKE :q", { :q => "%#{q}%" }]) }
  scope :by_age, where(["people.age = ?", q])
  scope :tagged, lambda { |q| joins(:tags).where(["tags.name LIKE :q", { :q => "%#{q}%" }]) }
end
```

Refer:

1. [Scopes in Rails 3](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/02/19/scopes-in-rails-3/)
2. Scopes overhaul section in [How Rails 3 Makes Your Life Better](http://railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-3-makes-life-better)

Now, merge the scopes only when the condition is met. As I understand your condition, is the value for a particular search item is nil (like, age is not given), do not search for that scope.

```
  ...      
  def search(object)
    interested_fields = ['name', 'age', 'email', 'tags']
    criteria = object.attributes.extract!(*interesting_fields) # returns { :age => 20, ... }

    scope = object.class.scoped

    build(criteria).each do |k, v|
      scope = scope.send(k.to_sym, v)
    end

    scope.all
  end

  # This method actually builds the search criteria.
  # Only keep param which has value and reject the rest.
  def build(params)
    required = ['name', 'age', 'email', 'tags']
    params.delete_if { |k, v| required.include?(k) && v.blank? }

    params
  end
...
```

Refer:

1. [extract!](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/extract!)